# Managing and Storing Facebook Friend Data using Facebook API 2.3 in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xcode6

so I've thoroughly searched existing questions on this forum, but all seem out of date for Graph API 2.3. I'm trying to retrieve facebook friends list for a specific user id, and am aware that it will only return those who have granted the app the same permissions. I use the following:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:coreData.userID parameters:nil]
              startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result2, NSError *error) {
                  if (!error) {
                     // NSLog(@"%@",coreData.userID);

                      NSArray *friends = [result2 objectForKey:@"data"];
                      NSLog(@"%@ friends", friends[0]);
                      //NSLog(@"%@", friends);
                  }
                  else {
                      NSLog(@"Error");


                  }
}];
```

I have set up appropriate test accounts whom are friends so it should work, I'm just having trouble interpreting result2 to obtain an array of friends id's in XCode 6?

Thanks

Comment: 1) You're title can be better. This is not related to "xcode", but to "iOS". 2) What is the values for `result2` that you are getting? What is working, and what is not? Your question is incomplete currently.

Comment: The following result logs "(null) friends". A similar procedure works accurately when replacing objectForKey:@"data" to objectForKey:@"id", and returns my user ID. From what I understand, for the API call "/{friendlist-id}", the result2 object should have fields: id, name, list_type for all authorised user friends (coreData.userID in my case). Since the call successfully returns my ID, I feel I am not populating *friends correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The `graphPath` that you are using is incorrect. You are requesting just the user ID. You should request the `/friends` edge, e.g. `/{user-id/friends` or, as a shorthand, `/me/friends` (in this case, "me" is the alias for the current user of the access token provided).

```
[FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

See also the code snippet example in the documentation for [/user/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends#read).